# Mongo "top keyword movers" and absolute sum of subtractions

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have been trying to calculate the "top keyword movers". For example, the following documents in a date range from 2013-12-19 to 2013-12-23:

```
{
    "domain" : "www.mytestingdomain.com",
    "keyword" : "elegant",
    "google_rank" : 10,
    "date" : ISODate("2013-12-19T00:00:00Z")
}
{
    "domain" : "www.mytestingdomain.com",
    "keyword" : "elegant",
    "google_rank" : 5,
    "date" : ISODate("2013-12-20T00:00:00Z")
}
{
    "domain" : "www.mytestingdomain.com",
    "keyword" : "elegant",
    "google_rank" : 1,
    "date" : ISODate("2013-12-21T00:00:00Z")
}
{
    "domain" : "www.mytestingdomain.com",
    "keyword" : "elegant",
    "google_rank" : 5,
    "date" : ISODate("2013-12-22T00:00:00Z")
}
{
    "domain" : "www.mytestingdomain.com",
    "keyword" : "elegant",
    "google_rank" : 1,
    "date" : ISODate("2013-12-23T00:00:00Z")
}
```

Displays how a particular keyword "elegant" has moved in this specific date range.

My question (Using Mongo Aggregate framework):

There is a way to calculate this movements? For example:

```
10 - 5 = 5
5 - 1 = 4
1 - 5 = -4 --> abs --> 4
5 - 1 = 4
---------------------------
absolute total: 5 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 17 --> in this case "seventeen" is the absolute sum of moves that I am looking for.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current schema the type of calculation you are trying to achieve would have to be approached from your application code, by iterating the results of a normal `find()` to calculate the required sums.

The Aggregation Framework (as at MongoDB 2.4) does not support queries that reference previous documents processed in the same pipeline step.  There is an open feature suggestion you can upvote/watch in the MongoDB issue tracker: [SERVER-4437: aggregation: support windowing operation on pipelines](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4437).

If you want to adjust your schema to calculate using the aggregation framework, you could include an extra field like `previous_google_rank` so the rank differences could be calculated per-document.  Calculating via application code would be the more efficient and obvious choice, though.